# How to access theme settings from another site on another site on Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have a Wordpress multisite and from one of the sites on the multisite, we need to be able to access the site name and logo that are stored in the theme settings on another site on the network.  Does anyone know how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ID of the subsite you want in the network.

```
$blog_details = get_blog_details( array( 'blog_id' => ID of subsite goes here ) );
```